# Access JMX enabled application running behind an HTTP proxy server

Tags: java, jmx, remote-access, proxy-server

I have a JMX enabled Java application (Java 1.5) sitting behind an HTTP proxy server. So I cannot access it directly through the JConsole.

A solution I imagine would be to have an in-VM JMX client in my application which collects the statistics and the configuration data from the JMX server and posts it to my external server periodically over HTTP through the proxy. My external server replies back with any configuration changes if needed and the in-VM JMX client propagates those changes to the JMX server which applies them to the application.

I'd guess this to be a scenario frequent enough to have solutions already addressing it. Is there any helper framework/library to enable such access over HTTP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure this is what you need, but there is a very nice JMX to REST bridge called [Jolokia](http://www.jolokia.org) out there. If you add it to your application, you will be able to interact with JMX through REST interface that will be accessible via HTTP proxy like any other HTTP traffic. So not only you are tunneling JMX through HTTP, but you are also exposing it in much nicer format (JSON over HTTP).

It has pretty good [documentation](http://www.jolokia.org/features-nb.html), also see my [showcase](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2011/03/jolokia-highcharts-jmx-for-human-beings.html).

Comment: I suppose I cannot make calls to my application behind the proxy server. So my application has to make calls to my external server. How is Jolokia helpful in such a situation?

Comment: I might have misunderstood your problem. If you have a web application that is available through proxy like Apache (but of course JMX port is not), Jolokia will be just another application you can access via HTTP through proxy. If this is not the case, I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is hosted on Linux/Unix, you can set up port forwarding to it(using putty, ssh or other tools).  Then fire up JConsole and specify local host and port to channel requests to your remote server.  SSH Port forwarding is pretty trivial to setup and you will find ample examples on web.

Comment: I'm afraid setting up port forwarding isn't an option available to me.